# Calling payable function from contract with parameters

Tags: contract-development, payable

How do I call this function from my contract and send ether to it?

```
abstract contract MainAcceptedOffers {
    function accept(uint _acceptance, address payable _casher) public payable virtual;
}
```

```
contract MainOffers {
    MainAcceptedOffers mainAcceptedOffers;
    constructor(address _mainAcceptedOffers) {
        mainAcceptedOffers = MainAcceptedOffers(_mainAcceptedOffers);
    }
    function accept() {
        mainAcceptedOffers.accept(0, msg.sender);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try - > `mainAcceptedOffers.accept.value("the value in Wei")(0, msg.sender);`

The smart contract should have ether